# Number of occurrences in two strings using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I need help writing a function that defines the number of occurrences of two string arguments. The function returns the number of times a character from the first argument occurs in the second argument.

Example: occurances('fooled','hello world') should evaluate to 7 (1 'e', 3 'l', 2 'o', 1 'd')

Needs to incorporate a 'for loop'.

---

Thanks for the assistance everyone, much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything? It seems like this is homework, please show the code you're stuck with.

Comment: @user3374113 if you edit in your attempt into the question, people will be more receptive.

Comment: For [reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223856/questions-on-so-asking-us-to-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension approach:

```
In [738]: def occurances(fst, sec):
     ...:     return sum(sec.count(c) for c in set(fst))

In [739]: occurances('fooled','hello world')
Out[739]: 7
```

Make it to a for-loop:

```
def occurances(fst, sec):
    osum=0
    for c in set(fst):
        #try it yourself :)
    return osum
```

Or as @SvenMarnach and @JayanthKoushik mentioned, if not using `set`:

```
In [738]: def occurances(fst, sec):
     ...:     return sum(c in fst for c in sec)
```

which also runs with O(mn) in time (m, n is the length of `fst` and `sec`). You can make it O(m+n) by making `fst` a `set`:

```
In [738]: def occurances(fst, sec):
     ...:     fst=set(fst)
     ...:     return sum(c in fst for c in sec)  #checking "in set" is O(1)
```

Comment: Comprehension need not use set. You could just do: len([c for c in sec if c in fst])

Comment: Nor need for a set if your solution is O(mn) anyway.  Just `sum(c in fst for c in sec)` will do.  You could use a set to reduce the time complexity to O(m+n) though by doing `fst = set(fst)` before that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach won't _not_ using a set cause **multiple** outputs? Like so: `(1 'e',1 'e'....)`?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: It produces the desired result if you iterate over the letters of the *second* string and only count them if they appear in the first string.  My proposed solution doesn't count *how often* they appear in the first string.  (The desired return value is just a single number.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach oh yes right. My bad. Does that improve efficiency?

Comment: @SvenMarnach checked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `defaultdict` and count the occurrences if an element of first appears in the second. And then sum up all the values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ele_count = defaultdict(int)
def occurances(first, second):
  count = 0
  for ele in second:
    if ele in first:
      ele_count[ele] += 1

  for item in ele_count.values():
    count += item

  print count
```